# How can I get inside parentheses value in a string?

Tags: java, android

How can I get inside parentheses value in a string?

```
String str= "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)";
```

I need only AED text.

Comment: i can't get idea how to split inside parentheses. Would you help highly appreciated

Comment: @Muraliganesan Look at some java tutorial on handling strings. The feature you are asking for is pretty basic and is most probably explained in some java tutorial.

Comment: Although the substring solution worked for this particular case, you should really get used with Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Compiles and prints "AED". Even works for multiple parenthesis:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Main
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     String example = "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)";
     Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\(([^)]+)\\)").matcher(example);
     while(m.find()) {
       System.out.println(m.group(1));    
     }
  }
}
```

The regex means:

- `\\(`: character `(`
- `(`: start match group
- `[`: one of these characters
- `^`: not the following character
- `)`: with the previous `^`, this means "every character except `)`"
- `+`: one of more of the stuff from the `[]` set
- `)`: stop match group
- `\\)`: literal closing paranthesis

Comment: but only takes capital letters inside the parenthese.

Comment: now my answer will never be picked xD and I still like it best... invoques less classes and is cleaner...

Comment: @Daren: but if the string is huge and you have many paranthesis, it will be slow. The method I used here will only search for the match just before it is needed. But SO is pretty random, you just have to write many answers and some of them'll get picked.

Answer (score 25):

> i can't get idea how to split inside parentheses. Would you help highly appreciated

When you split you are using a reg-ex, therefore some chars are forbidden.

I think what you are looking for is

```
str = str.split("[\\(\\)]")[1];
```

This would split by parenthesis. It translates into split by `(` or `)`. you use the double `\\` to escape the paranthese which is a reserved character for regular expressions.

If you wanted to split by a `.` you would have to use `split("\\.")` to escape the dot as well.

Comment: This answer would also match `)AED(`, `)AED)`, and `(AED(`.

Comment: What are `[` and `]` in the expression?

Answer (score 23):

This works...

```
String str = "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)";
String answer = str.substring(str.indexOf("(")+1,str.indexOf(")"));
```

Comment: Much more readable than the spaghetti code in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

I know this was asked over 4 years ago, but for anyone with the same/similar question that lands here (as I did), there is something even simpler than using regex:

```
String result = StringUtils.substringBetween(str, "(", ")");
```

In your example, `result` would be returned as "AED". I would recommend the StringUtils library for various kinds of (relatively simple) string manipulation; it handles things like null inputs automatically, which can be convenient.

Documentation for substringBetween():
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substringBetween-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

There are two other versions of this function, depending on whether the opening and closing delimiters are the same, and whether the delimiter(s) occur(s) in the target string multiple times.

Comment: Use  `StringUtils.substringsBetween` to get an array of all matches.

Answer (score 4):

You could try:

```
String str = "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)";
int firstBracket = str.indexOf('(');
String contentOfBrackets = str.substring(firstBracket + 1, str.indexOf(')', firstBracket));
```

Comment: Good one. But what if the placeholder is something like ' or % ?
Say String str = "United Arab Emirates Dirham %AED%";
How do we achieve the same without RegEx?

Answer (score 2):

I can suggest two ways:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(getParenthesesContent1("United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)"));
        System.out.println(getParenthesesContent2("United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)"));
    }

    public static String getParenthesesContent1(String str){
        return str.substring(str.indexOf('(')+1,str.indexOf(')'));
    }

    public static String getParenthesesContent2(String str){
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^.*\\((.*)\\).*$");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        if (matcher.matches()){
            return matcher.group(1);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can try different techniques like using

```
 string.indexOf("(");
```

to get the index
and the use

```
string.substring(from, to)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression:

```
String text = "United Arab Emirates Dirham (AED)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".* \\(([A-Z]+)\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: `\(` - this is illegal escape sequence, `\\(` should be used.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Cœur is probably correct, but unfortunately it did not work for me.
I had text similar to this:

```
mrewrwegsg {text in between braces} njanfjaenfjie a {text in between braces}
```

It was way larger, but let's consider only this short part.

I used this code to get each text between bracelet and print it to the console:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while(m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group().subSequence(1, m.group().length()-1));
}
```

It might be more complicated than @Cœur answer, but maybe there is someone like me, who can find my answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

The below method can split any String inside any bracket like '(. {. [, ), }, ]'.

```
public String getStringInsideChars(String original, char c){
    this.original=original;
    original = cleaning(original);
    for(int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++){
        if(original.charAt(i) == c){
            String temp = original.substring(i + 1, original.length());
            i = original.length();//end for
            for(int k = temp.length() - 1; k >= 0; k--){
                if(temp.charAt(k) == getReverseBracket(c)){
                    original = temp.substring(0, k);
                    k = -1; // end for
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return original;
}

private char getReverseBracket(char c){
    return c == '(' ? ')' :
           c == '{' ? '}' :
           c == '[' ? ']' :
           c == ')' ? '(' :
           c == '}' ? '{' :
           c == ']' ? '[' : c;
}

public String cleaning(String original) {
    this.original = original;
    return original.replaceAll(String.valueOf('\t'), "").replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
}
```

You can use it like below :

```
getStringInsideChars("{here is your string}", '{')
```

it will return "here is your string"