# Find and replace parentheses in a string

Tags: java, android

I have the following string:

```
"Learning (Java) to create app on (Android)"
```

I would like to change it to:

```
"Learning <strong>Java</strong> to create app on <strong>Android</strong>"
```

That means replacing the parentheses with strong tags to make it bold. How I can do that with Java.

Comment: try this ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584018/how-can-i-get-inside-parentheses-value-in-a-string

Comment: `str.replace("(", "<b>").replace(")", "</b>")` Assumes that parentheses are properly balanced.

Comment: @DaminiMehra that question relates to getting the string inside of parentheses, this question is about replacing parentheses with html tags.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way as well

```
String test = "Learning (Java) to create app on (Android)";

System.out.println(test.replaceAll("\\((\\w*)\\)","<b>$1</b>"));
```

Comment: Glad that helped you .. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The other answer's suggestion of using `String#replace` would do the trick if you only had one set of parentheses. However, your example has more than one set of parentheses, so what you want to use is `String#replaceAll`.

For instance:

```
String foo = "Learning (Java) to create app on (Android)";
foo = foo.replaceAll("(", "<strong>");
foo = foo.replaceAll(")", "</strong>");
```

Comment: I try to build but have error as bellow capture
https://gyazo.com/aff5ebb2a62ab0a0d28b24ccd258192b

Comment: @user3328309 My code was missing a semicolon (`;`) at the end of the last line but I edited my answer and corrected it. Just add a semicolon and that should fix it.

Comment: thanks sir, I found the result as I expected with supporting of @Sanjeev

Comment: `String#replace` also replaces all sets of parentheses, not just the first. And it has the advantage of not using regular expressions, just exact substring matching.